# CSS File taking no effect on HTML (e.js) file

Tags: html, css, ejs

I'm sorry if this is really a simple fix, but I've tried everything I know and I can't get this working.

I am trying to get the `404.css` files to take effect on the `404.ejs` file, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure I'm doing something wrong in the CSS files or if the file path is not right.

If anybody could guide me in the right direction, that would be great!

`404.html`

```html
<div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/pages/css/404.css'/>
    <h1>Looks like you're lost!</h1>
    <p1>There is nothing here for you! Please return to our homepage.</p1>
</div>
```

`404.css`

```css
div {
    padding: 50px;
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

File Structure 
[image]

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Try putting the <link> tag in the <head> tag

Comment: @mega12345mega I updated my file to the following
```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/404.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <container id="content">
        <h1>
            Looks like you are lost!
        </h1>
        <p1>
            Please return to our homepage by clicking here
        </p1>
    </container>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still nothing

Comment: Is the dot in front of the "href" the issue? Or the "/"? Try changing ./css/404.css to css/404.css

Comment: @mega12345mega Still nothing.

Comment: Try also adding    type="text/css"    into the newest version; it doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: @mega12345mega Nope, same result.

Comment: This problem must be asked 10 times a day on SO alone and it's always the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing whatever this does (sorry but if anybody could explain to me)

I added this to my main file

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'pages')));
```

This made the CSS suddenly start to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This must be specific to your editor; I have never seen that.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the editor?

Comment: I'm running the website itself in the browser. I'm using JetBrains WebStorm